# How to create enum in Redshift?

Tags: sql, enums, amazon-redshift

I want to create an enum type on redshift but not able to.

```
CREATE TYPE status AS ENUM ('Yes', 'No');
```

The error is :

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
CREATE TYPE status AS ENUM ('Yes', 'No')

ERROR: syntax error at or near "ENUM"
  Position: 23

CREATE TYPE status AS ENUM ('Yes', 'No')
                  .    ^
1 statement failed
```

The version I am using is:

```
PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.1885
```

Not able to figure out whether the query is wrong or not supported by this version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As explained in the Redshift [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-datatypes.html), Redshift does not support enumerated types.

Unfortunately, Redshift doesn't support the two work-arounds that come to my mind:  check constraints and foreign key constraints (where the values go in a reference table).

My advice is to create a reference table for the type and to use a foreign key reference.  Even though Redshift does not enforce the constraint, at least the intention will be clear.